# How do I order groups alphabetically?

Tags: crystal-reports

It may be a bit more complicated then that, but here goes.

This report lists overtime on a weekly basis. Each driver has worksheets that outline details of a given shift. The user selects a period of a week, and I have some formulas that fill variables with their hours worked for each day of the week. The lines look something like this:

CKL09844 - LATTA   Scott    9.5   8.6    10.5    11     0 hourlysum, etc.

The records are grouped by the 'Driver ID' - the first field - but I'd like to have them listed in alphabetical order. Only the group footers are being displayed currently. Anyone have any advice?

Edit: List them alphabetically by last name, that is.

Answer (score 2):

You can either

1. Change the group to the 'LastName, FirstName' field or fields instead of driverID or
2. Use a summary to sort the group. You can do this by inserting a summary like `maximum({table.name},{table.driverID})` and placing it in the footer and then suppressing it (It's stupid but Crystal needs this field actually in the report before it will allow you to access the next step). Then, go to "Report -> Group Sort Expert -> For this group sort: All" and select the summary you just made.

Comment: Thanks Ryan - I'll give it a shot. Another quick one for you: I'm generating an overtime report, and while Crystal Reports can group shifts into weeks, it uses a standard Sunday-Saturday week; I need a Monday-Sunday week(ie, Sept 12-18th inclusive). Is there any way to change this setting, or am I stuck with writing a complex formula?

Comment: There are a bunch of ways to do this. One is outlined in this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7531322/change-the-definition-of-a-week).