# Change the definition of a 'Week'?

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm generating an overtime report, and while Crystal Reports can group an employee's shifts into weeks, it uses a standard Sunday-Saturday week; I need a Monday-Sunday week(ie, Sept 12-18th inclusive). Is there any way to change this setting, or am I stuck with writing a complex formula?

Answer (score 4):

I don't know of a setting that will allow you to do this, but the group formula is not *too* bad. The following will give you the week number/index in the year using Mondays as the start of the week.

```
datepart("ww",{table.date},crMonday)
```

You will probably want to incorporate the year, too. You can ensure proper sorting by year and week with this

```
totext(datepart("yyyy",{Orders.Order Date}),"####") + " " 
+ totext(datepart("ww",{Orders.Order Date},crMonday),"##")
```

Comment: Hey Ryan, thanks for the advice. What exactly do I do with those formulas? Heh, I've only been using CR for a few days. I understand I can use a formula for the Group Sort Order, but I'm not sure how to apply what you've given me. Any more help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Just group on the latter formula. There's no need to mess with specifying a sort order. The formula returns "yyyy ww" where yyyy is a 4-digit year and ww is a 2-digit week index into that year, so it should sort just fine the way it is.

Comment: Be aware that if you are in the part of the world that uses ISO-standard dates and week numbering `datepart` gives erronous results around new year.
See http://stackoverflow.com/q/13701063/909134

Comment: I also added "Week" before the weekNum, looks legit now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could group by `{table.date} - 1`.

Comment: If done this way, just be careful to not print the Group Name or this formula anywhere on the report itself as the dates would be wrong.