# Correct ISO week numbering in Crystal Reports XI

Tags: crystal-reports, iso, crystal-reports-xi, week-number

How can I get the ISO-8601 week number of a given date in Crystal Reports XI?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Crystal Reports supports the `DatePart`-function which can give you the ISO week number of a given date.

```
NumberVar week := DatePart("ww", date, crMonday, crFirstFourDays);
```

However, in Crystal Reports XI there is a bug that gives erronous results round new year. The best solution is probably to create an own function getISOWeekNumber:

```
Function (optional DateVar d := CurrentDate)
NumberVar week := DatePart("ww", d, crMonday, crFirstFourDays);

// Correct for that CR doesn't handle the fact that the last days of a year can belong to week 1 of the next year:
if week = 53 and DatePart("ww", cDate(year(d) + 1, 1, 1), crMonday, crFirstFourDays) = 1 then
    week := 1

// A bug in CR makes DatePart return values like 9363 for days in January that belongs to the last week of the previous year.
else if week > 53 then
    week := DatePart("ww", cDate(year(d) - 1, 12, 31), crMonday, crFirstFourDays);

week;
```

To get the "week-year" of a specific date, you could then use the following function:

```
// Returns the year to which the ISO week of the specified date belongs.
// E.g. 2012-12-31 will return 2013, as that date belongs to week 1 of 2013.
Function (optional DateVar d := CurrentDate)

NumberVar week := getISOWeekNumber (d);

if week = 1 and month(d) = 12 then
    year(d) + 1
else if week > 10 and month(d) = 1 then
    year(d) - 1
else
    year(d);
```

Comment: As counter-intuitive as it is to me that Dec. 31, 2012 should be considered week 1 of 2013, it looks like you're right. This is a bug with 2008 as well.

Comment: If you want every week to have 7 days (which you as good as always want) you have to decide what to call the week that spans the new year. Calling it "2012-53/2013-01" would perhaps be more intuitive, but arguably not better. ISO-8601 simply names the whole week after which year most days in the week belongs to.